# Passing Date Parameter variable to both SQL Server and Oracle datasets in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a SSRS report that will contain data from an Oracle dataset and a SQL Server dataset. Since SSRS uses `:` for an Oracle parameter and `@` for SQL Server - is there a way to pass the date parameter to both datasets from within SSRS?

Comment: You don't mention how you are accessing both the servers? Multiple datasets  and then a lookup or linked server and a union in your query?

Comment: multiple datasets and then lookup.